# Azure Maps Data-driven Style Expressions using dynamic code variables

Tags: azure-maps

I have an Azure Maps project where I use a lot of data-driven (style) expressions to choose how I visualize my map. However, I've stumbled upon a problem that I cannot find an answer to.

*Context*: My map is used to render several objects. There is also a search field that can be used by the user to search for specific objects. When objects are searched, all searched objects remain visible and the other objects disappear. I wanted to implement this using one layer so I created the following filter expression:

```
['any', 
 ['==', 
  ['boolean', ['get', 'selectedStock', ['literal', renderOptions]]], 
  ['boolean', false]], 
 ['==', 
  ['get', 'selected'], 
  ['boolean', true]]
]
```

`renderOptions` is an object containing key-value pairs that indicate the current settings for rendering. One key-value pair is `selectedStock`, which indicates whether a search for objects has happened or not (boolean). This value starts as `false`. Each feature in my map has certain properties. The `selected` property indicates whether the feature is the result of the current search. This value starts as `false`. Upon searching for objects, a result of map features is calculated and each of these features get their `selected` property value switched to `true`, until the search is reset or a new search is executed.

A feature should only pass the filter when: No search has taken place OR (a search has taken place) and the feature is in the search result (all features that are in the result get the `selected` property set to `true`). However, it seems that the `['get', 'selectedStock', ['literal', renderOptions]]` part of the expression is only evaluated at the start when creating the layer, making it always evaluate to `false`. It never evaluates to `true`, even when I use debug and see that the corresponding key-value pair is now `true`.

Is this intended behaviour, or am I overlooking something? Resetting the map via code also resets the filter and this seems to update the value when it has changed from its initial value.

*As a side-question*: Are the `['type', value]` (e.g. `['boolean', true/false]`) expressions needed when the value is clearly a certain type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the filter will not update as you change the values in the `renderOptions`. To be honest, I'm not even sure that is even working in the first place. Data driven style expressions are processed in WebGL (GPU) which doesn't have access to local variables/objects. So to get the filter to work initially, you likely will need something like this:

```
['any', 
 ['==', renderOptions.selectedStock, false], 
 ['==', ['get', 'selected'], true]
]
```

When a value in the render options is update, you need to reset the filter property on the layer.

```
layer.setOptions({
filter: ['any', 
 ['==', renderOptions.selectedStock, false], 
 ['==', ['get', 'selected'], true]
]
})
```

Comment: I already ended up using the filters in this way, but thanks for the confirmation! :)